# How to create a vertical navigation with hover dropdowns that also appear vertical?

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

I've reached a bit of a problem that I'm not sure how to work-around. I'm creating a vertical navigation for a website I'm working on, however all the vertical navigation menu's that I've seen display the hover drop-down menu to the right or left of the navigation. I'd like to have the drop-down menu appear under the link rather than to the side of the link.

For example: In my menu when a user hovers over or visits the "Treatments" I'd like the list "allergies & sinus, head & neck, etc" to appear below it rather than to the right.

I've tried to look around to see how I could go about doing this but haven't found any really good examples or help. I might need some javascript? I'm not sure, but if it's necessary I can add it I'm just not that familiar with javascript as I am with HTML and CSS.

My HTML:

```
<h4>ENT Services</h4>
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <li><a href="http://www.accentmd.com/florida-ent/ent-services.html">Treatments at Accent EMT</a>
    <ul class="sidebar-sub-menu">
            <li><a herf="http://www.accentmd.com/florida-ent/allergy-sinus.html">Allergy &amp; Sinus</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.accentmd.com/florida-ent/hearing-balance.html">Hearing &amp; Balance</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.accentmd.com/florida-ent/dizziness-imbalance-disorder-center.html">Dizziness &amp; Imbalance Disorders</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.accentmd.com/florida-ent/thyroid-parathyroid-center.html">Parathyroid Disorders</a></li>
     </ul></li>
    <li><a href="ttp://www.accentmd.com/florida-ent/ent-services.html#pediatric">General &amp; Pediatric ENT</a>
    <li><a href="http://gainesvilleaesthetics.com/">Facial Plastic &amp; Reconstructive Surgery</a></li>
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```
.sidebar-nav {
    height:auto;
    list-style:none;
    width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear:both;
    width: 50%;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.sidebar-nav li ul {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

.sidebar-nav li:hover .sidebar-sub-menu {
    position: relative;   
    margin-top: -27.5px;
}

.sidebar-sub-menu li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left:90%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 180px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index:1;
}

.sidebar-sub-menu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.sidebar-nav li:active .sidebar-sub-menu {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:-27.5px;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked your CSS a bit to best isolate the desired behavior, maybe from here on you can keep tweaking the rest to your benefit. Note you've also had a typo on the allergy & sinus `<a href="">` (says `<a herf="">`)

```css
.sidebar-nav {
  height: auto;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  /* height: 25px; */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 50%;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* added CSS */

.sidebar-nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sidebar-nav ul li a:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}

.sidebar-nav ul {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<h4>ENT Services</h4>
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
  <li><a href="http://www.accentmd.com/florida-ent/ent-services.html">Treatments at Accent EMT</a>
    <ul class="sidebar-sub-menu">
      <li><a href="http://www.accentmd.com/florida-ent/allergy-sinus.html">Allergy &amp; Sinus</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.accentmd.com/florida-ent/hearing-balance.html">Hearing &amp; Balance</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.accentmd.com/florida-ent/dizziness-imbalance-disorder-center.html">Dizziness &amp; Imbalance Disorders</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.accentmd.com/florida-ent/thyroid-parathyroid-center.html">Parathyroid Disorders</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="ttp://www.accentmd.com/florida-ent/ent-services.html#pediatric">General &amp; Pediatric ENT</a>
  <li><a href="http://gainesvilleaesthetics.com/">Facial Plastic &amp; Reconstructive Surgery</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    display: none;
}

a:hover + div {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a>Hover me timberrrs!!</a>
<div>here is your stuff</div>

</body>
</html>
```